# c# Converting json string with list of objects to a c# object

Tags: c#, json

I'm tring to convert a string json to c# object,

I've already read several replies in here regarding to similar questions but none of the solutions worked.

This is the json obj

```
{
   "Customer": {
     "data_0": {
        "id": "273714",
        "FirstName": "Zuzana",
        "LastName": "Martinkova"
     },
     "data_1": {
        "id": "274581",
        "FirstName": "Ricardo",
        "LastName": "Lambrechts"
     },
     "data_2": {
        "id": "275190",
        "FirstName": "Daniel",
        "LastName": "Mojapelo"
     },
     "data_3": {
        "id": "278031",
        "FirstName": "Sulochana",
        "LastName": "Chandran"
      }
   }
}
```

I created the following objects according to the json obj

```
public class Customer
{
    public List<Data> Customers{ get; set; }
    public Customer()
    {
        Customers = new List<Data>();
    }
}
public class Data
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

As for my code I made a small console app example with all the solotions I found here

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["filepath"].ToString());

        //solution 1
        JObject jsonone = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
        var collection_one = jsonone.ToObject<Customer>();

        //solution 2
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var collection_two = serializer.Deserialize<Customer>(jsonString);

        //solution 2
        var collection_three = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer> (jsonString);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); ;
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Ths json string I get from a 3rd party webservice so just for the example I'm reading the json from a txt file,
the jsonString param value after reading is:

```
"{\"Customer\":{\"data_0\":{\"id\":\"273714\",\"FirstName\":\"Zuzana\",\"LastName\":\"Martinkova\"},\"data_1\":{\"id\":\"274581\",\"FirstName\":\"Ricardo\",\"LastName\":\"Lambrechts\"},\"data_2\":{\"id\":\"275190\",\"FirstName\":\"Daniel\",\"LastName\":\"Mojapelo\"},\"data_3\":{\"id\":\"278031\",\"FirstName\":\"Sulochana\",\"LastName\":\"Chandran\"}}}"
```

On every solution I make the collections count is 0, data objects are not including inside the list.

Can someone put some light on it and tell me what is wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need two classes, keep your `Data` class and you need another class that has a single `Dictionary<string, Data>` property called "Customer".  If you want to have different C# property names then the JSON you need to use the JSON.NET `[JsonProperty(name="")]` attribute

Comment: @maccettura but  I have 2 classes , 1 for the `data` and 2 has `list<data>`

Comment: Your JSON isnt a list though, its a dictionary.  And your property is called "Customers" and your JSON is clearly labeled "Customer"

Comment: You don't have any object named `Data`, you have one `data_01`, and a `data_02`, etc, so, like @maccettura says, you do not have a list of `Data`, you have a `Dictionary<string, Data>`;

Comment: @maccettura 
Your solution solve it, I didn't realise a dictionary will act different.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is a `Dictionary<string, Data>`, *not* a `List<Data>`.  In addition to that your property is called "Customer", *not* "Customers".  To solve this you need to change a couple things:

```
public class Customer
{
    //JsonProperty is Used to serialize as a different property then your property name
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Customer")] 
    public Dictionary<string, Data> CustomerDictionary { get; set; }
}
public class Data
{
    public string Id { get; set; } //You should make this "Id" not "id"
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

With these class definitions you can easily use the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` and `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` methods:

```
Customer customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(json);
string newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer);
```

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MrT59X) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

Add empty class
`public class Customer : Dictionary<string, Data>{}  //empty class`

And the update your existing code

```
//solution 1    
JObject jsonone = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

//Add this line
var token = jsonone.SelectToken("Customer").ToString();

//solution 2 - update jsonString to token variable created above.
var collection_three = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(token);
```